# Why does Acer PC's BIOS not recognize USB external drive as boot device

Tags: boot, usb, debian, bios

I have installed Debian 8.9 on an USB external drive. `lsusb` identifies the external drive as follows:

```
ID 0bc2:2320 Seagate RSS LLC USB 3.0 bridge [Portable Expansion Drive]
```

I would now like to boot an [Acer Veriton M6620G](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75750/how-can-i-find-the-hardware-model-in-linux) PC from that drive. However, the PC's BIOS does not seem to recognize it as boot device for it appears neither under `nth Boot Device` (nor `Hard Disk Drives Priority` nor `Removable Devices Priority`) in the BIOS.

If I insert a USB memory stick instead, the BIOS recognizes and lists it both under `nth Boot Device` and `Removable Devices Priority`.

I've double-checked that the USB external drive (as well as the USB memory stick) is [bootable](https://superuser.com/questions/329467/how-to-see-if-usb-stick-has-mbr). The external drive apparently uses USB 3.0, whereas the memory stick USB 2.0. After booting Debian 8.9 on the PC from another boot device, it recognizes the USB external drive normally on the OS level (with `lsusb`, etc.). The system BIOS version is `P01-All`.

Is there a known reason why this PC's BIOS does not recognize this USB external drive, and is there a way to successfully boot it from that device?

Comment: Does the hard drive have a UEFI boot partition on it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I guess no. (My answer to "Force UEFI installation?" during Debian installation to the USB external drive was "No".)

Comment: Welp, you're probably going to need one now that it's 2017.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've rerun the Debian installation and this time answered "Yes" to "Force GRUB installation to the EFI removable media path". The BIOS now recognizes the USB external drive e.g. under `EFI Devices`. If you want to write up your comments as an answer, I shall accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has become increasingly popular for PCs to obscure or eliminate "legacy" booting in favor of [UEFI booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_booting). Ensuring that the appropriate UEFI boot partitions are created when installing an OS will allow it to boot on UEFI-only systems.